# Which languages are used today for low-level programming?

Tags: programming-languages, low-level, embedded-systems

When I hear low-level programming, such as for drivers, embedded systems, operating systems, etc., I immediately think about C and perhaps C++. But mainly C.

But what other languages are also used for these kind of tasks? Today, I mean, not what *has been* used.

Answer (score 13):

Normally low level programming such as driver programming is a mixture of an [assembly language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) and C.

The assembly language is used to talk to the hardware and C is used to talk to the kernel.

Comment: I meant languages on a higher level than assembly, but your point is still valid, of course. =)

Comment: Depends on the operating system, on Windows or Linux there is no need for assembly language when writing drivers. You can access the hardware just fine with C.

Comment: The only time you really work with assembly is when dealing with architecture specific quirks, usually when working on something like a virtual memory manager. The programmer writing a device driver, however, is rarely exposed to this. They use the facilities that exist.

Answer (score 8):

[Ada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ada_%28programming_language%29) is still used in safety/mission-critical systems, as it still offers relatively unparalleled safety features.

It was compulsory to use Ada up until the late nineties within the DoD, and some other areas, but is no longer, so is not as heavily used as it once was.  But it can still be found in highly critical uses, avionics, nuclear power, etc.

The modern versions have object orientation and good support for parallel processing, so is entirely useful still.

Comment: I think we will use Ada in one of the embedded systems courses I'm taking in spring.

Comment: @gablin: Aye, it's commonly used in embedded systems, quite a good choice for that.

Answer (score 6):

I did some research for 8-bit programming a little while ago (hobby related; I wanted to try building some basic electronics). Other than C and Assembly, the only languages I found mentioned favorably for these tasks were Scheme and Forth.

Comment: +1 Oh yes, building basic electronics is going to be my hobby soon and I can't wait to start using [Make: Electronics](http://www.amazon.com/Make-Electronics-Discovery-Charles-Platt/dp/0596153740) book for this hobby

Answer (score 3):

[Cython](http://www.cython.org/) is one example. Not for embedded systems, but for drivers and other low level programming it's used more and more in the Python world as a replacement of C. You get both a compiled Python, but also low level access and type hints for speedups.

As a Python fanatic that's what I use, although admittedly very rarely and so far not in any serious context.

Comment: Never heard of it before, but thanks for the enlightment. =)

Comment: ("more an more" -> "more and more")

Comment: I don't think Cython is actually that common for low level programming. I feel like its typically used to create wrappers around C and C++ to give lower level access and access to typical C or C++ libs.

Comment: So, low level programming, then. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did some work on embedded systems through last years using C and [Lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Check out [eLua](http://www.eluaproject.net) as well.

-- 
EDIT: Here in Brazil we do have a "new technology" for Digital TV's, called [Ginga](http://www.ginga.org.br/index_en.html). It's really a standard, but in this standard the [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) language is used as one source of embedded language. The other one is Java.

I guess we can cite Java as well, for some special systems like [JavaCards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Card). If those are not embedded systems, than I don't know what embedded means... :)